# Pushforward of crystals in mixed/positive characteristic

Tags: reference-request, crystalline-cohomology, crystals

Is there a good reference for pushforward of crystals along smooth maps in mixed/positive characteristic with respect to the crystalline site? Intuitively I'm confused on what the pushforward looks like. Is it supposed to just be the sheaf pushforward together with a crystal structure? It seems like this defines some crystal? But I'm not sure it will have the correct properties (adjunction, etc). I'm happy to work completely derived.